# AppleEvents/sandbox: Returning errAEPrivilegeError, not entitled to send an AppleEvent to the process

Tags: macos, sandbox, appleevents

I want to create InDesign document using Apple Script using Sandboxing.
My Apple Script is:

tell application Adobe Indesign CS5.5
make new document
end tell

My Entitlement Entries are :
[image]

In Adobe InDesign CS5.5.app Info.plist Bundle identifier is com.adobe.InDesign
I try both entry com.adobe.InDesign and com.adobe.indesign.

When I run my sandbox application it only start Adobe InDesign Application but not create any document in it.
I check Console app (available in /Applications/Utilities/), look for sandboxd violations in the All Messages system log query it give following error :

AppleEvents/sandbox: Returning errAEPrivilegeError/-10004 and denying dispatch of event ascr/gdte from process because it is not entitled to send an AppleEvent to this process.

What Entitlement entry should be to reate InDesign document ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i check the id of Adobe InDesign (OSX 10.10, InDesign CC 2015) it says "com.adobe.InDesign" <- register the capital letters! For me it works with that ID in sandbox mode with your entitlements.

I've heard from others that they rather use

```
tell application id "com.adobe.InDesign" to doSomeHandler()
```